# How to user Boiler plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, boilerplate

I have create a simple custom WordPress plugin using BoilerPlate to call an Laravel application API.

I have configured everything, I have no errors. But I do not know exactly how to display the returned data into a page or something similar.

```
public function getRecords($id)
{
   $cache_name = ‘records_’ . $id;
   $cache = new FileStore(new Filesystem($cache_name . ‘.txt’), __DIR__ . ‘/cache’);

 // If cache exists
 if ($cache->get($cache_name)) {
    return $cache->get($cache_name);
 } else {
    try {
     // Try to get records
     $client = new GuzzleHttp(‘https://api.hello.com/records/1399394access_token=w3r2232r’);
     $request = $client->get()->send();
     $records = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);

     // Save records in cache
     $cache->put($cache_name, $records, 600);
     return $records;
   } catch (GuzzleHttpExceptionBadResponseException $e) {
 $raw_response = explode(“n”, $e->getResponse());
     throw new IDPException(end($raw_response));
   }
 }
}
```

For this example, how can I display the returned variable 'return $records;' to homepage for example? Just a test, to see how it works.

This is the class:

class Plugin_Name_Public {

```
/**
 * The ID of this plugin.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 * @var      string    $plugin_name    The ID of this plugin.
 */
private $plugin_name;

/**
 * The version of this plugin.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 * @var      string    $version    The current version of this plugin.
 */
private $version;

/**
 * Initialize the class and set its properties.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @param      string    $plugin_name       The name of the plugin.
 * @param      string    $version    The version of this plugin.
 */
public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

    $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
    $this->version = $version;

    $capsule = new Capsule;

    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways but one of the simplest would be to create a `shortcode` within the plugin boilerplate and do the request.

I am not familiar with the boilerplate you used but in typical fashion for something inside a class would look like this.

```
class Hello_Plugin{
    public function my_shortcode_func($atts,$content = ''){
        // Make request and return it
        return "Hello";
    }
    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {
         add_shortcode("my_shortcode",array($this,"my_shortcode_func"));
    }
}
```

So after you just place `[my_shortcode]` within a specific page.

Note: Some boilerplate place shortcode initialization outside the `__construct` function so in general try to follow the standard of the boilerplate.

Other method include having a template file with a public object or function to access the plugin information.

Comment: Thank you Musk. It worked. Could you please give me a reference for the other method which includes the template file?

Comment: @codi05ro Depends on the context but you could also do `echo do_shortcode("[my_shortcode]")` within a specific plugin or theme template has long as the shortcode exist it will be executed. Or access the plugin with a static function within a specific template file. etc.. I will likely edit the answer soon to show more examples. :)